# Python3.7 & Windows : incorrect unicode characters in docstrings in interactive mode

Tags: windows, unicode, python-3.7, interactive, docstring

Save following program as `test.py`:

```
def f():
    """àâùç"""
    return
print("àâùç")
```

and execute it in a Windows `cmd`-window in interactive mode:

```
python -i test.py
```

The `print`ed text is correct, but when I call `help(f)` I get scrambled eggs:

```
P:\>python -i test.py
àâùç
>>> help(f)
Help on function f in module __main__:

f()
    ÓÔ¨þ
```

Changing the codepage to 65001 brings up classical mystery cards instead:

```
P:\>python -i test.py
àâùç
>>> help(f)
Help on function f in module __main__:

f()
    ����
```

Is there any (easy) workaround ?

Comment: Try `chcp 1252` as `help()` stands on `ACP` code page (`reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage" -v ACP`).

Comment: Seems like a bug that print() works correctly and help() encodes to ANSI (1252 on U.S. and Western European Windows).  The default encoding for the Windows terminal is "OEM ANSI" 850 on Western Euopean Windows and are the mis-decoded characters `ÓÔ¨þ` you see.  `chcp 1252` does make help print correctly.  `print(f.__doc__)` displays the doc string correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`help()` has two bugs where the implementation of the pager is to write to a temp file and shell out to `more`.  From `pydoc.py`:

```
def tempfilepager(text, cmd):
    """Page through text by invoking a program on a temporary file."""
    import tempfile
    filename = tempfile.mktemp()
    with open(filename, 'w', errors='backslashreplace') as file:
        file.write(text)
    try:
        os.system(cmd + ' "' + filename + '"')
    finally:
        os.unlink(filename)
```

The file is opened with default file encoding (`cp1252` on U.S. and Western European Windows) which won't support characters outside the Windows-1252 character set (don't make Chinese help documentation, for example), and then shells out to a command (in this case, `more`) to handle paging.  `more` uses the encoding of the terminal (OEM ANSI: default cp850 in Western Europe and cp437 in the US) so help will look corrupt for most characters outside the ASCII set.

Changing the terminal code page with `chcp 1252` will print the characters correctly:

```
C:\>chcp 850
Active code page: 850

C:\>py -i test.py
àâùç
>>> help(f)
Help on function f in module __main__:

f()
    ÓÔ¨þ

>>> ^Z


C:\>chcp 1252
Active code page: 1252

C:\>py -i test.py
àâùç
>>> help(f)
Help on function f in module __main__:

f()
    àâùç

>>>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works fine on Windows 10, python 3.7. Strangely (I would believe) it doesn't work with python 3.4 on a Windows 7 box, where it also breaks the `print`ed output. But nevermind!